# Efficient way to write an IF Condition

Tags: if-statement, plsql

I have the following logic to be implemented in a PLSQL code.

```
IF (A = true AND B = true THEN
    DO_SOMETHING(); 
ELSIF A = true THEN
    DO_SOMETHING2();
ELSIF B = true THEN
    DO_SOMETHING3();
ELSE
    DO_SOMETHING4()
END IF;
```

I feel like there should be a efficient way to write this one.
Could you please suggest if there is any.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have a problem with your current code.

Comment: Maybe a [seached case statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-C7CBBE66-5E51-444E-BE92-C23ED662FE4D)?

Comment: @Abra I think it would be the same even if I use case statement.
But there was a good explanaton on that ink. Thank you.

Comment: You can at least leave out "= true" form those expressions... Booleans can be tested simply with IF b THEN ..... also, if your list of conditions is particularly long maybe you should table drive it and call the right branching functions dynamically using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ? That would collapsed it all to a single call.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit comparing boolean variables with boolean literal. Simple use boolean variables as boolean expression:

```sql
IF A AND B THEN
    DO_SOMETHING(); 
ELSIF A THEN
    DO_SOMETHING2();
ELSIF B THEN
    DO_SOMETHING3();
ELSE
    DO_SOMETHING4()
END IF;
```

Also you can rewrite your conditional code into two nested IF-operators:

```sql
IF A THEN
  IF B THEN
    DO_SOMETHING(); 
  ELSE
    DO_SOMETHING2();
  END IF;
ELSIF B THEN
  DO_SOMETHING3();
ELSE
  DO_SOMETHING4();
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use cases, but I don't know if this is what you are asking for tho

```
CASE
    WHEN A = true AND B = true THEN
        DO_SOMETHING();
    WHEN A = true THEN
        DO_SOMETHING2();
    WHEN B = true THEN
        DO_SOMETHING3();
    ELSE
        DO_SOMETHING4();
END CASE;
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php